Broken keyboard button. Remapping keys trouble
New Ubuntu user here
I recently broke the key 1 in my keyboard, above my letter keys.
I tried to follow the below guide
How can I remap keyboard keys?
but I face the following issues

The key is broken, meaning I cannot press it to catch the events via xev. (Note that this key has 2 functions, the number and the exlamation mark, using Shift. My main problem is the exclamation since for 1, I can use the numeric pad)

I am thinking of changing the grave/tilde key, since they are next to the broken one, but I am not sure how usable they are (aside from home directory perhaps). The other option would be the Insert key. What would be my best options here?

Even if I follow the guide, as far as I understand, the fix is temporary and I need to make permanent changes in this folder /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc. However this is not a valid folder in my setup (Ubuntu 24.04). How can I make this fix stay?


Thank you very much for the advice :)

It would seem obvious but use an external keyboard, assuming laptop. Or just change the keyboard if desktop. You could spend many days if not weeks trying to remap this key.

It would be good to have mentioned the type of keyboard or provide a picture.  It may have been the case that replacing the key cap is easy, or even that replacing the keyboard is easy, depending on what type of keyboard it is.

You can do it with xbindkeys and xdotool.
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xdotool

Run xbindkeys -d and it will create the default ~/.xbindkeysrc
Add the following:
# Use Shift+F1 as Shift+1
"xdotool key shift+1"
  release+shift + f1

Then, run xbindkeys -p to poll the new setting.
